# How to count the sum of Invoices by last year using SQL in Rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to count all amount of invoices for last year. I do it using helper method but, as far as I know, there is better way using only one query to database with SQL function SUM().

My invoices table:

```rb
create_table "invoices", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string "title"
  t.text "description"
  t.string "category"
  t.decimal "amount"
  t.bigint "user_id", null: false
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_invoices_on_user_id"
end
```

My current method with multiple database queries and sum amount using Ruby:

```rb
# invoice.rb model has invoices_for_year scope

scope :invoices_for_year, -> { where('extract(year from created_at) = ?', Time.now.strftime("%Y").to_i) }

# invoices_controller.rb in index method has @invoices_for_year

invoices = Invoice.all.available_for(current_user)    
@invoices_for_year = invoices.invoices_for_year

# and inside helper I calculate the all amount
def count_year_spend
  @invoices_for_year.reduce(0) { | sum, invoice | sum + invoice.amount }
end
```

How to calculate the amount in one request using SQL inside Ruby?

Comment: [`sum`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-sum) should work.

Comment: thanks Stefan, this is really easy using sum method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try

```
Invoice
  .where(created_at: (Time.current.beginning_of_year..Time.current.end_of_year))
  .sum(:amount)
```

Or you could define a scope in your model like

```
scope :by_year, -> (year) { where('extract(year from created_at) = ?', year) }
```

and use it like this

```
Invoice.by_year(Date.today.year).sum(:amount)
```